# no .apk is created when running the project after getting the error could not find apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I tried to run my android code and I got the following error "could not find *.apk". Then I opened the project's property and uncheck is library.

I was able to run the code while my phone is connected in debug mode instead of the emulator. Now there is no apk in the project directory.

why is this happening??
how make it create the .apk??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have "Is Library" checked in the properties, it is normal that no apk is built, as having it checked means it is intended to be used by other projects and built into their apk files.

Now that you have unchecked "Is Library" and been able to build and run the code on your phone, the apk file must have been built.  The apk file is normally located in the `bin` subdirectory of your project after you've built in debug mode in eclipse.